# Speeding up double for loop in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, if-statement, vectorization

I have the following code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(active)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(UniqueTracks)){
    if (((grepl(active$Route1[i], UniqueTracks$Route1[j], perl = TRUE)) & (grepl(active$FlightLevelTrack[i],UniqueTracks$FLs[j], perl = TRUE)) & (active$ThirtyWestTime[i]>=UniqueTracks$Activation[j]) & (active$ThirtyWestTime[i]<=UniqueTracks$Deactivation[j]))){
    active$CalculatedTrack[i]<-UniqueTracks$NATTrack[j]
   }
  }
}
```

The purpose of it is to find whether one dataframe value is found inside another dataframe variable (grepl). It also needs to find whether the times in one dataframe are inbetween two other times in the second dataframe.
Hence the need for the double for loop.

In one dataframe (active) there are 20573 rows and 120 columns. In the second dataframe (UniqueTracks) there are 477 rows and 7 columns.

Currently it is taking hours to run and am looking for help in speeding everything up.

I have read that vectorization could help speed things up but have never used one before and know little about them. Would this help speed thing up? Or is there another way to do this?

```
active
Route1   FlightLevelTrack    ThirtyWestTime
a b c          360          2017-02-01 12:01:34   

UniqueTracks
Route1           FLs               Activation         Deactivation     NATTrack
z a b c d    360 380 390 400      2017-02-01 11:30:00   2017-02-01 16:00:00      F
```

Desired Ouput

```
active
Route1   FlightLevelTrack    ThirtyWestTime         CaluclatedTrack
a b c          360          2017-02-01 12:01:34            F
```

Comment: If you could provide a small sample of the data and what your desired output is, it would be much easier to help you solve this.

Comment: I have added a line for each dataframe @Benjamin

Comment: Please use `dput()` to provide example data.

Comment: Should your output have one row for each row in `active` (20573) or one row for each combination of `active` and `UniqueTracks` (20573 * 477)?

Comment: @Benjamin one row for each row in active

Comment: A quick way to eliminate the inner loop is to replace it with the `ifelse` function.  This will provide a performance increase, and with additional effort there are other possible performance enhancements.

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e, I'll give that a go :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm admittedly a noob, but, do you need to use a loop here at all. Try merging data frames by  Route1. Then remove NA's in the variable you want to be the same between data frames (looks like FlightLevelTrack to me). This can all be done in one step by using inner_join() function from the dplyr package. Seems pretty quick to me

```
 active <- data.frame(Route1 = c('a','b','c'), 
FlightlevelTrack = c(360,360,355))



UniqueTracks <- data.frame(Route1 = c('z','a','b','c','d'), 
FLS = c(360,380,390,400,1),NATTrack = c('F','F','F','F','F'))


output <- dplyr::inner_join(UniqueTracks , active ,by = "Route1")
output
```

Hope this helps.